# HTML 5 Beginner. How to achieve this layout?

Tags: html, web

I'm new to html/html5, but not to programming, and i'm trying to code my personal website. I've read many resources and tutorials on the basics but I'm looking for some tips on how to begin achieving the layout I want.

In my layout ([here](http://i49.tinypic.com/2u94kzs.jpg)) I'm looking to have the left half of my page as a fixed navigation panel with an image highlighting the current page, then with each option the right side refreshes to a new independently scrolling page and the highlight image animates in the nav panel to the new option.

How should I begin to achieve something like this? I just need a push in the right direction to the type of elements/scripts/whatever I will need to implement.

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like you want to use `iframe`. Don't go into that territory. It's crude and, IMO, not exactly appealing.

Comment: Check out Twitter Bootstrap (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/). It has tons and tons of really smart, really useful widgets--including "affix" (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#affix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example to help you start out:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kQGzR/)

You'll notice the text on the right slides out of the screen when you scroll but the green box stays in the same position. This is done with a slight bit of CSS.

The navigation div on the left is styled with `position: fixed;`. This keeps the navigation div in one place at all times.

In contrast, the content div on the right is styled with `position: absolute;` with a `left: 25%` set. The widths of the navigation div and content div are set in percentages. This allows the content to take up the same relative screen space whether the window is larger or smaller. Your content will adapt to your viewers resolution.

Using an `<iframe>` will is one possible solution to altering the content in the right hand content div. Another would be to use `ajax` but that is getting a little more advanced as you now must understand client and server scripting in order to receive the full benefits from it.

[iFrame](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)

[Ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.ASP)

If you're information is static and will not change often, you could considering making a single page web app with multiple templates that are appended to the content div.

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

[jQuery Templates Plugin](http://jtemplates.tpython.com/)

jQuery is really good as well for learning JavaScript and makes building dynamic client side applications a breeze.

They also have `ajax` support as well:

[jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Hope this helps.

Good luck and Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

You have the menu housed within an element that is set to `position: fixed;`

Position fixed will make sure the menu doesn't move around on the page regardless of scrolling the rest.

Then with javascript you can add an event listener for "scroll" on the window (or just the div you want to watch for scrolling). When this fires, check the scrollY property to see what range it is in and maybe highlight certain items in your menu.

Hopefully this leads you down the right path. It's a broad question, so here's a broad answer!

Answer (score 0):

I second the suggestion from [@Jeromy French](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1430996/jeromy-french) -- I think [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) , [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com) and other responsive frameworks have a lot going for them.

Here's an example using Bootstrap: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/2dF6s/

In addition to being HTML5, you can get a layout which works on everything from smartphones to wide desktops. It's not the only way to get a mobile friendly website, but it's one of several good options.

I think that with so much moving towards smartphones and tablets now, the more you can learn about responsive and mobile websites, the better off you will be in the future.

I think all the responsive frameworks use a grid based system, here's what the HTML looks like with Bootstrap:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row-fluid" align="center">
    <div class="span12">
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </div><!-- close span12 -->
</div> <!-- close row -->

<div class="row">

<div class="span3" id="side-nav" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="200">

<h5>Option 1</h5>
<h5>Option 2</h5>
<h5>Option 3</h5>
<h5>Option 4</h5>
</div> <!-- end span3 -->

<div class="span9">
<p>Main Content Here </p>
 </div> <!-- end span9 -->
</div><!-- end row -->
</div><!-- end containter -->
```

Good luck!